# How to login without system profile?

Tags: windows-server-2008, user-profile, profile

I am receiving 0x80070002 file missing error on starting server. server is running windows server 2008 r2.

After researching i got to this page http://blogs.technet.com/b/filecab/archive/2008/03/12/common-causes-and-solutions-to-backup-system-restore-and-complete-pc-backup-problems-updated.aspx and it says there is a profile missing at `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList`

i checked the registry, and there are only 3 profiles (system profile, local service, network service). I checked the same registry location in another computer and there are 5 profiles there (3 above mentioned and 1 user and 1 user backup).

it looks like there is no user profile.

How can i create a new profile?

P.S. i only have access to command prompt, GUI is not working.

Comment: Depending on where the cmd is running you could try creating a new user account and then using `runas` to create a profile for that account

Comment: The cmd is running in system32 folder. i created user account using the net user passoword /add command added the user to administrators group and restarted. but the profile is not created. how can i create a profile?

Comment: Go back to the cmd prompt and type the following `runas /user:<your new user> notepad` enter the password when prompted. This should create a profile for the user. If you can't run notepad try the same command but with `cmd` instead of `notepad`

Comment: It says `runas` is not recognized as an inernal or external command. I checked the windows\system32 dir and there is no `runas` executable file.

Comment: Are you in the recovery console cmd prompt by any chance?

Comment: I think so, i access the command prompt from window that appears after the error. other options in that window are `memory diagnostics` , `automatic repair` , `recovery` etc. Every other option has failed to run.